# How to check-in packages when using Go modules?

Tags: go, govendor, go-modules, go-packages

We currently are using `govendor` to manage packages in our `go` repository. Since we are using a lot of packages, we have decided to check-in the packages sources code into `vendor` folder, so that:

- Saving time downloading all packages every time the repository needs to be built in build machines.
- Avoiding the possibility of one package becoming unavailable online (being deleted, network issues, etc...)

I am interested to use the `modules` notion introduced in `v1.11`. However I can't seem to find a similar approach of check-ing in the packages instead of having to download all the packages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go modules provide a `go mod vendor` command that will create a vendor directory in your package root, same as glide or govendor or dep do.